# Find the eigenvalues of the operator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, eigenvalue

> A projection operator $P$ is defined as $P^2$=$P$. Use this definition to find the eigenvalues of this operator.

In this question is it necessary to define what the projection operator is? And won't the eigenvalue just be zero?

Comment: The eigenvalue will not always be zero. Also, this is a pure math question as well as a homework question, both of which are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

I am not giving a mathematical solution to your problem, as that can easily be found by a quick google search.

Instead, I prompt you to imagine the following, in hopes that it furthers your intuitive understanding of the problem:

Picture in your head a three-dimensional space. Take any one plane, e.g. the $x$-$y$-plane. Let, as an example, $P$ be the operator the projects a given vector onto that $x$-$y$-plane. Now, ask yourself:

What result do you get...

- ... when you project a vector that already is in the $x$-$y$-plane onto said plane?
- ... when you project a vector that is orthogonal to the $x$-$y$-plane, e.g. a vector in $\pm z$ direction, onto said plane?
- ... when you project any other vector, e.g. a vector that has nonzero components both in the $x$-$y$-plane, and the $z$ direction, onto said plane?

For each of these questions, additionaly think about whether the result is a multiple of the input vector, and if yes, what that multiple would be (since these multiples then are the eigenvalues).

Maybe drawing these situations onto a piece of paper helps you visualize the problem. Feel free to post your thoughts as comments to this answer, so we can discuss them.

Answer (score 1):

A normal operator with spectrum given by just the point $0$ is the zero operator. Clearly there are projections which are not the zero operator, so you might want to revise your argument.